# Ruby super initialization not passing argument correctly

Tags: ruby, initialization, super

I have a class Temperature, with two subclasses, Celsius and Fahrenheit, which in their initialize methods take an argument with a Fixnum as the temperature which then calls super initialize with the temperature as entry in a options hash.

However, if I call `Celsius.new(50)`, in the superclass initialization code I'm getting the error "NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each' for 50:Fixnum" meaning the original argument from the subclass constructor is not being passed as an options hash.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening!

Please see my code below:

```
class Temperature
    def initialize(opts={})
        opts.each { |k,v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) }
    end

    def self.from_celsius(c)
        Temperature.new(:c => c)
    end

    def self.from_fahrenheit(f)
        Temperature.new(:f => f)
    end

    def self.ftoc(n)
        (n - 32) * (5.0 / 9.0)
    end

    def self.ctof(n)
        n * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32
    end

    def in_fahrenheit
        @f.nil? ? Temperature.ctof(@c) : @f
    end

    def in_celsius
        @c.nil? ? Temperature.ftoc(@f) : @c
    end
end

class Celsius < Temperature
    def initialze(n)
        super(:c => n)
    end
end

class Fahrenheit < Temperature
    def initialize(n)
        super(:f => n)
    end
end
```

Comment: Not quite - it means it's calling the superclass's initialize with your "50" I don't know the solution... but that's what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spotted the problem:

```
class Celsius < Temperature
  def initialze(n)
  # should be initialize
     super(:c => n)
  end
end
```

Comment: hehe... we're all guilty of these ones ;)